# Android out of memory after first application run?

Tags: java, android

I have an application that will run fine the first time it is ran. Now if I leave the application and force stop it in manage applications and come back in it will crash with OutOfMemory. Why would it work the first time and run out of memory on subsequent calls?

Comment: I have no idea. You should at least provide your onCreate() method and the other lifecycle methods you are using. Otherwise we can not help you with this problem.

Comment: You have to give us some code otherwise we cannot help you studying this problem :)

Comment: Sounds like a big memory leak, but we need more information to really help.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no way to know with the information you provide. However that is totally possible, it is likely a process that runs when the app loads is leaking memory massively.